# wait for predefined time before exit the script

Tags: shell-script, kill

I have an app server running in my unix box with process name as `abc_test`. I have a shell script in which I have to stop my server using `/opt/abc/bin/stop`. Now sometimes my server doesn't get stopped so I need to check whether my process is still running or not. If it is running then sleep for some seconds and then check again whether process is still running or not. If after 5 minutes process is still running, then I want to exit successfully from the shell script but if the process is not running then exit successfully as well from the shell script.

So I came up with below script but I am not able to understand how to add this 5 minute thing in my below shell script. Does my below script will do exactly as I am thinking? I guess this might be improved as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/abc/bin/stop

# Wait for 10 second
sleep 10

# Number of seconds to wait
WAIT_SECONDS=300
# Counter to keep count of how many seconds have passed
count=0

while pgrep abc_test > /dev/null
do
    echo "server is still running."
    # Wait for one second
    sleep 1
    # Increment the second counter
    ((count++))
    # Has the process been killed? If so, exit the loop.
    if ! pgrep abc_test > /dev/null ; then
        break
    fi
    # Have we exceeded $WAIT_SECONDS? If so exit the loop
    if [ $count -gt $WAIT_SECONDS ]; then
        break
    fi  
done
```

Comment: `Does my below script will do exactly as I am thinking?`. Run it and see? (And then [edit] with your results, if not).

Comment: You could use the `SECONDS` variable to see how many seconds have passed since the script began.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `/opt/abc/bin/stop` doesn't block your script seem to work.
As *muru* suggested you could skip the `$count` variable and use the builtin `$SECONDS`. This would lead to code like this:

```
/opt/abc/bin/stop
# Wait for 10 second
sleep 10
# Number of seconds to wait
WAIT_SECONDS=300
while pgrep abc_test > /dev/null
do
    echo "server is still running. Seconds: $SECONDS"
    # Wait for one second
    sleep 1
    # Have we exceeded $WAIT_SECONDS? If so exit the loop
    if [ $SECONDS -gt $WAIT_SECONDS ]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

In case `/opt/abc/bin/stop` DOES block, just call it in the background like:

```
/opt/abc/bin/stop &
```